# FCM message composer target user segment has 0 users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have a Firebase cloud messaging app configured in Firebase for use with Web Push Notifications.

There is a web app with the required Javascript for subscribing to and receiving messages, using an HTML page and a service worker. The service worker is being installed as expected.

The web page code initializes Firebase and calls `messaging.getToken()`, which returns a token. I printed the token out to the console so I could use it for testing.

Using the Firebase message composer, **test** messages sent to that token are sent and received correctly.

However, attempting to send a message using the primary Composer flow does not work. Under Target, it is set to "User Segment," with the sole condition being App => The current Firebase app.

#### Expected result

In Composer, the number of users eligible for the campaign should be `100%`. When sending the notification, it is received by the service worker.

#### Actual result

No message is received. The number of users eligible is shown as:

> 0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 0
> [image: Composer dialog screenshot]

Hovering over the (?) shows that there are 0 users subscribed:
[image: popup showing "approximately 0 users registered"]

Why are there no potential users for this notification? I would expect there to be at least 1 user (me).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in order for this to work, you **need to activate Firebase analytics**, which requires version 7.0 or greater of the Firebase SDK.

In case it's helpful for anyone, here's the full code I ended up with for registering my own service worker and initializing Firebase, which allows the service worker to receive push notifications from the Firebase composer.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from './constants';

const initFirebase = serviceWorker => {
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
  firebase.analytics();

  // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.useServiceWorker(serviceWorker);
  messaging.getToken();
};

const registerServiceWorker = (path, scope) => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(path, { scope: `/${scope}/` }).then(
      registration => {
        initFirebase(registration);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
      }
    );
  }
};
```